# Shortest code to return current index number in string in 'for n in 'word': loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question about strings. I thought that this code:

```
for n in 'banana':
    print(n)
```

would return this:

0
1
2
3
4
5

But, of course, it doesn't. It returns the value at each position in the string, not the position number. In order for me to understand this better, I thought it might help to write the simplest possible program to achieve the output I thought I'd get:

```
count = 0
for n in 'banana':
    print(count)
    count += 1
```

This works, but surely there's a more direct way to access the position number that the current iteration is looking at? Can't see any methods that would achieve this directly though.

Comment: Try `enumerate()`

Comment: enumerate() is the right answer, but ``for i in range(len('banana'))`` is also a common idiom

Comment: Thanks both, I had a go, didn't make a good job of it! Riccardo Bucco has (I think) given a pretty definitive answer for me below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all equivalent:

```
i = 0
for n in 'banana':
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

```
for i, w in enumerate('banana'):
    print(i)
```

```
for i in range(len('banana')):
    print(i)
```

```
print(*range(len('banana')), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thats excellent, very illuminating.  I had cobbled together a very clumsy bit of code involving enumerate and re.sub, which looked awful and only partially solved the problem. Your 2nd solution looks closest to my idea of directly accessing the indexes, rather than having to reconstitute them through 'len' or the value of a count. Thanks, very pleased to have learned something!

Comment: It seems strange that deleting ', w' from that code returns the index value, plus formatting, instead of just the indices. I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the other answer, `enumerate()` works:

```
for idx, character in enumerate('myword'):
    print(f"Index={idx} character={character}")
```

It is worth pointing out that in this Python treats strings as arrays. When you have `"abc"[0]` it will return `a`. And, similarly, when you say 'give me each element in some array' it will simply give you the element, not the index of that element - which would be counterintuitive.

Comment: Yes, it does seem counterintuitive to me. I wonder how this works at the level of ram memory; that index number must be needed to get an address to access the value, it's just a shame we can't acces that index directly ourselves. Feels like that ought to be useful, somehow.